# Jenkins SCM polling: optimise latency without killing the build farm

Tags: jenkins

I've got a project hosted in a (private) github repository and have continuous integration locally. The build takes quite a while (3 hours on success) and runs on a shared server, so I don't want it to be running continuously.

At the moment, I've configured Jenkins to poll github once a day in the evening. This is ok, and avoids spamming our build servers, but it would be nice to improve the latency a bit.

I was wondering about a rule like: "After taking N minutes for a build, hold off for the next N minutes" (or something similar). That way, if the build is horribly broken and fails quickly, a developer could push up a fix and see the results but we still don't end up with back-to-back 3 hour runs.

Any ideas on how I might get this working? I can run any scripts locally on the build server to do funky orchestration.

Alternatively, is this a terrible idea? If so, what could I do more sensible?

Answer (score 0):

Try Quiet Period feature for that purpose. *https://jenkins.io/blog/2010/08/11/quiet-period-feature/*

This would help you set N minutes of time before building next Job, available to set globally in Jenkins.

Comment: As far as I can see, that doesn't allow me to control the length of the quiet period based on the last run time. Also, I'm aiming for "low latency, low throughput" - if nothing has run for ages, I'd like a commit to trigger a build as soon as possible. If I understand correctly, the quiet period kind of does the opposite (presumably it's designed for SCMs like CVS, where big atomic pushes aren't possible).

Comment: You are using GitHub SCM. Quiet period would work fine in your case. To trigger a Job as soon as code is pushed or a patch is created in repository, please try multi-branch pipeline [plugin](https://github.com/gitbucket/gitbucket/wiki/Setup-Jenkins-Multibranch-Pipeline-and-Organization)